# How would I trigger updateElements for BaseElementIndex from a plugin's JavaScript?

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype, javascript

If I wanted to update the Elements listing based on an action taken from a plugin, would it be possible to do this?

**Setup:**

- We're on an Elements listing page.
- We filter the results with a search query.
- We then click an Element's name to move to its individual editing page

**The Problem:**

Currently in my tests with Google Chrome if I:

- Filter a list by a search query (say `lastName::T*` on the Users listing page),
- Click on one of the usernames
- Hit "Back"

My search is not saved, i.e., I'm returned to a non-filtered list.

My workaround to this is to write a simple JS plugin that stores your search query - if populated - when you navigate away from the page. I then re-populate the search query when you re-enter the page but I have to tell Craft to execute it, IE to fire `updateElements`.

My current workaround for this is to fire a `change` event on the search box if the search query is stored and it's not an Ajax request. It works, it just feels kind of hacky.

So I'm wondering if there's a more native, less hacky solution.

Comment: Hey Peter, can you provide more context? What page in the CP would this be happening on, what exactly is this “onSourceSelectChange” event you’re referring to, etc.

Comment: Hi Brandon, absolutely. I'll update the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry Peter, didn’t get a notification that you had responded. (I think SE only gives notifications for comments that include @username, unless the comment is on your own post.) Just provided an answer.

Comment: No problem whatsoever! Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this would be to provide your own Javascript class that overrides Craft.BaseElementIndex, which stores the latest search value in localStorage:

```js
MyElementTypeIndex = Craft.BaseElementIndex.extend(
{
    onAfterHtmlInit: function()
    {
        // Do we have a stored search value?
        if (this.instanceState.searchVal)
        {
            this.$search.val(this.instanceState.searchVal);
        }

        this.base();
    },

    updateElements: function()
    {
        // Store the current search val in localStorage
        this.setInstanceState('searchVal', this.$search.val());

        this.base();
    }
});

// Register this as the official index class for this element type!
Craft.registerElementIndexClass('MyElementType', MyElementTypeIndex);
```

Save that file somewhere in your plugin’s resources/ folder (let’s say it’s craft/plugins/myplugin/resources/js/index.js), and then include it from your plugin’s `init()` function:

```php
class MyPlugin extends BasePlugin
{
    // ...

    public function init()
    {
        if (craft()->request->isCpRequest())
        {
            craft()->templates->includeJsResource('myplugin/js/index.js');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks Brandon!